# How can I remove the blank space on the left of a bootstrap horizontal description list?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

There's too much empty space and it looks weird. Here's the code:

```
<div class="col-sm-4" style="border-style: dotted; border-width: 1px;">
      <dl class="dl-horizontal">

          <dt>Tag:</dt>
          <dd><img src="..." class="width-60 img-rounded"></dd>

          <dt>Frente:</dt>
          <dd>...</dd>

          <dt>Verso:</dt>
          <dd>...</dd>

          <dt>Descrição:</dt>
          <dd>...</dd>

          <dt>Coleira:</dt>
          <dd>...</dd>
      </dl>
</div>
```

And here's the result:

[image]
 How can I remove that blank space on the left? (I have tried this [Bootstrap horizontal description list whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706555/bootstrap-horizontal-description-list-whitespace)  but it didn't work)

Also, is there anyway I can center the Tag text that describes the image?

Thanks.

Comment: The dl takes the whole div, tried `<dl class="dl-horizontal" style="padding-left: -50px;">`, nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can over-ride the bootstrap style that sets the margin for the description.

Add a custom class to your surrounding dl. e.g.

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal my-class">
```

Then add your css to change the margin to what you want:

```
.my-class.dl-horizontal dd{
   margin-left:170px
}
```

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using?